# How to install Node.js into a Javascript IDE Flatpak

Tags: linux, fedora, flatpak

I installed the Flatpak for Webstorm (a Jetbrains Javascript IDE), known as `com.jetbrains.Webstorm` from Flathub. The pack itself comes with no binaries or development sdks, solely the ones needed to get Webstorm running.

I installed `org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.node16` for the Node.js SDK, but when I got on Webstorm, `/usr/bin/node` was still empty. My question is, how can I install Node.js into my Webstorm Flatpak? Do I have to build a completely new one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with WebStorm itself, but you should be able to mount Node.js into it by manually running `flatpak install org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.node16` and then launching WebStorm with the `FLATPAK_ENABLE_SDK_EXT=node16` environment variable set.

It doesn't appear to take if specified via Flatseal or `flatpak override`, so you'll need to use your desktop's launcher editor or a wrapper script. to set it before the `flatpak run` command.

My source is that this works for me:

```sh
flatpak install org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.rust-stable
FLATPAK_ENABLE_SDK_EXT=rust-stable flatpak run --devel --share=network --filesystem=home:rw --command=bash org.freedesktop.Sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Endless OS forum post](https://community.endlessos.com/t/getting-vs-code-to-recognize-flatpak-nodejs/16576), what you're planning is unfortunately impossible:

> That does not work that way
>
> [The flatpak NodeJS] extension can be used by Flatpak Developers/Packagers to include the NodeJS Runtime environment in the Flatpak if the packaged application depends on it.

It seems like the `com.jetbrains.WebStorm` Flatpak does not include this extension. The suggested solution is to simply install NodeJS on the host using "traditional" means, such as the [operating system's package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/), by downloading from the [official NodeJS download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) or using a NodeJS version manager such as [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [Volta](https://volta.sh/). WebStorm will pick it up.